# React for loop doesn't send incremental data to function properly

Tags: reactjs, for-loop

Can someone explain why this loop when rendered and clicked on always sends the one same value to my function

```
class AppointmentSelect extends React.Component {

changeDate = x => {
    console.log(x);
}

render () {

    let daysArray=[];
    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) { 
      daysArray.push( 
        <div className="day" onClick={() => this.changeDate(startDate+i) }>
          <h1>Mo</h1>
          <p>{ startDate + i }</p>
        </div> 
      );
    }
    return <>{ daysArray }</>

}}
```

changeDate always sends the i as a 7 so it renders as

`Mo 1  Mo 2  Mo 3  Mo 4  Mo 5  Mo 6  Mo 7`

But clicking any number sends the value "7"

How can I get this to work?
Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the correct way to render a list in React. Almost always, you'll want to map over an array instead - This should work:

```
return (<>
   {
     new Array(7).fill().map((_, index) => ( 
        <div className="day" onClick={() => this.changeDate(startDate+index) }>
          <h1>Mo</h1>
          <p>{ startDate + index }</p>
        </div> 
     )
   }
</>)
```

Comment: Hey, this doesn't seem to loop at all. I think it must be close though. Thanks

Comment: Still nothing unfortunately

Comment: Sorry had another look and turns out it doesn't work with the () brackets after the =>. I removed the (brackets) around the div and it works. Thanks!

Comment: Oh... It was the semi-colon there :) Ive removed it now